# How does AWS Data Migration Service actually work with MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, aws, amazon-dms

I'm very confused as to how AWS Data Migration Service is actually achieving it's replication from an on prem MS SQL 2019 instance to RDS 2019.

I understand from the documentation that tables with a primary key use SQL Server replication, and those without use SQL Server Change Data Capture.  I have a trial run set up that consists of one table with a primary key and one table without.  It is successfully replicating to the RDS instance.  All inserts, updates and deletes and replicated for the table with the primary key.  All Inserts and deletes are replicated for the table with no primary key, but updates are not.

I can see a replication publication has been set up, but there are no subscription.  It is clearly able to replicate because the data is moving to RDS, but I don't see how without a subscription.

CDC does NOT appear to have been set up.  There are no cdc tables created in the database and `is_cdc_enabled` is still 0 in `sys.databases`.  Yet the data is replicating to RDS - at least inserts and deletes.

I did read in my attempts to understand this that AWS holds a transaction open and can read the subsequent log requests, but I can't see any open transactions in `sys.dm_exec_requests`.  Both methods of replication seem to be happening by wizardry to me at the moment.  Can anyone shed any light on mechanically what is going on here?

Comment: >>>I did read in my attempts to understand this that AWS holds a transaction open There is no need to keep the transaction open, all it needs is to  prevent the transaction log to by cleared until some other thing similar to log reader of sql server reads from log and can release those records, so the only thing they really need is to activate something that will retain log records in the log to make them being read by DMS

Comment: Thanks Sepupic.  So if all it is doing is putting a marker transaction in the log and then scanning through the log from that transaction, why does it create a publication at all?  Why is CDC mentioned if it's not used and why does the non-PK table pick up inserts and deletes, but not updates?

Comment: I've just tried as you did to understand how it works, we no longer considered it as valid solution for us as it does not preserve IDENTITY property that is crutial for our db, in my opinion they have no their mode to retain the transactions in the transaction log so they just set up standard replication for doing this for them